# Test Class Coverage for Get Property

Tags: apex, unit-test

I used a get property in a controller how can I get the coverage for that method in my test class

**My Controller:**

```
public class VisitRaisedDateTime {
public String RecordId;
public Decimal tvalue;
public decimal businessMillisecondsDiff;
public decimal businessMinsDiff ;
public decimal hourDiff;
public decimal businessHoursDifferen ;
public decimal minDiff ;
public integer  hour;
public integer  hour1;
public integer minute;
public String raisedhours; 
public boolean differenthours;
public List<Opportunity> OppList{get;set;}
public DateTime raiseddte;
public DateTime rdte;
public String dtFormat ='dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm';

public VisitRaisedDateTime(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    RecordId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }

public boolean getRaisedDateandTime(){

  OppList= [SELECT Name,Raised_Date_Time__c,Arrived_in_Site__c,Visit_Priority__c,Reactive_Sheet__c,Maintenance_Sheet__c 
                       FROM Opportunity WHERE Raised_Date_Time__c!=Null AND Visit_Priority__c !=Null AND Arrived_in_Site__c!=Null AND 
                       /*Reactive_Sheet__c!=Null AND Maintenance_Sheet__c='No' AND */ ID=:RecordId ];

  System.debug('=====inside the method=====');

  for(opportunity ac: OppList) {


    if(ac.Arrived_in_Site__c != null && ac.Raised_Date_Time__c != null && ac.Visit_Priority__c!=null  && ac.Arrived_in_Site__c > ac.Raised_Date_Time__c){

            businessMillisecondsDiff = decimal.valueOf((ac.Arrived_in_Site__c.getTime() - ac.Raised_Date_Time__c.getTime()));
            businessMinsDiff = businessMillisecondsDiff / (1000*60);
            businessHoursDifferen = businessMillisecondsDiff / (1000.0*60.0*60.0);
            minDiff = businessHoursDifferen.setScale(2);//(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            system.debug('-----before corrected hours:'+minDiff );
            hour =integer.Valueof(minDiff);
            //hour = Math.Mod(integer.Valueof(minDiff),60);
            system.debug('-----hour :'+hour);
            minute = Math.Mod(integer.Valueof(businessMinsDiff), 60);
            system.debug('-----minute :'+minute);
            raisedhours= hour+'.'+minute;
            system.debug('-----corrected hours:'+raisedhours);
    }
    System.debug('=====Outside For Loop=====');
   if(ac.Visit_Priority__c != null){
      if(ac.Visit_Priority__c == '2 Hour'){
          tvalue=2.00;
          system.debug('$$$ tvalue:' + tvalue);
      }else if(ac.Visit_Priority__c == '3 Hour'){
          tvalue=3.00;
          system.debug('$$$ tvalue:' + tvalue);
      }else if(ac.Visit_Priority__c == '4 Hour'){
          tvalue=4.00;
          system.debug('$$$ tvalue:' + tvalue);
      }else if(ac.Visit_Priority__c == '8 Hour'){
          tvalue=8.00;
          system.debug('$$$ tvalue:' + tvalue);
      }else if(ac.Visit_Priority__c == '24 Hour'){
          tvalue=24.00;
          system.debug('$$$ tvalue:' + tvalue);
      }else if(ac.Visit_Priority__c == '3 Day'){
          tvalue=72.00;
          system.debug('$$$ tvalue:' + tvalue);
      }else if(ac.Visit_Priority__c == '5 Day'){
          tvalue=120.00;
          system.debug('$$$ tvalue:' + tvalue);
      }else if(ac.Visit_Priority__c == '10 Day'){
          tvalue=240.00;
          system.debug('$$$ tvalue:' + tvalue);
      }
   }

    if(raisedhours!=null && tvalue!=null){
      if(decimal.valueOf(raisedhours) > tvalue){
             differenthours=true;
      }else{
             differenthours=False;
      }
    }
   system.debug('----afterdifference-----'+differenthours);
  }
  return differenthours;   
 }
}
```

**Test Class:**

In this getting error

> "Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject:
>   List at line 8 column 71"

```
@isTest(seeAllData=true)
Public Class VisitRaisedDateTimeTest{

@isTest Static void VisitRaisedDateTimeTests(){
 List<Opportunity> Oppid;

      Oppid = [SELECT Name,Raised_Date_Time__c,Arrived_in_Site__c,Visit_Priority__c,Reactive_Sheet__c,Maintenance_Sheet__c 
                       FROM Opportunity WHERE Raised_Date_Time__c!=Null AND Visit_Priority__c !=Null AND Arrived_in_Site__c!=Null Limit 1];

      apexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('id',String.valueOf(Oppid.id));
      ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(Oppid);
      VisitRaisedDateTime controller= New VisitRaisedDateTime(sc);
      controller.OppList= Oppid;
      List<Opportunity> op=controller.getRaisedDateandTime();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your method is returning a boolean but in your test you are trying to assign it to a List of Opportunities:
`List<Opportunity> op = controller.getRaisedDateandTime();`

Try the following line instead of the one above: 
`Boolean differentHours = controller.getRaisedDateandTime();`

In addition I would recommend reading the [Apex Testing Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) and apply them to your test cases.

EDIT:

Upon further inspection there is issues with the lines -

```
apexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('id',String.valueOf(Oppid.id));
```

`ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(Oppid);`

OppId in this case is actually defined as a *List* of Id's. The ApexPages.StandardController expects an instance of an sObject (e.g. Opportunity) therefore this should be changed to something like the following:

`apexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('id',String.valueOf(Oppid[0].id));`

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(Oppid[0]);
```

Fixing the lines highlighted will allow your test class to compile which in turn will allow the test method to provide some coverage on your method.

Comment: Hi Jim, again the same issue after replacing your line: this is the-Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Opportunity> at line 8 column 71

Comment: Hi Karti - check out my updated answer : )